# how to convert array of object into object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of object and i cant convert it into an object. The array of object that i have is as below:

```
var x = [{
    name: "a",
    items: [{
         name: "b",
         items: [{
              name: "c"
              }]
         }]
    },
    {
    name: "d",
    items: [{
         name: "e",
         items: [{
              name: "f"
         }]
    }]
}];
```

and i want to convert it into object like this:

```
{
name: "a",
items: [{
    name: "b",
    items: [{
        name: "c"
    }]
  }]
},{
name: "d",
items: [{
    name: "e",
    items: [{
        name: "f"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I used one of the stackoverflow solution

```
function toObject(arr) {
      var rv = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
         rv[i] = arr[i];
      return rv;
}
```

But it convert as follows:

```
{
 "0":{
    "name":"a",
     "items":[{"name":"b","items":[{"name":"c"}]}]},
 "1":{
     "name":"d",
     "items":[{"name":"e","items":[{"name":"f"}]}]}
 }
```

So, how to get the object in the format i gave?

Comment: you only have 1 item in the array, why not `x = x[0];`? Is there more code to this??

Comment: Actually there are two items in the array, i want it in a single object.

Comment: The example you provided is not an object. There are two objects separated with a comma. How should it work?

Comment: @Thinker the output you wan is not an object

Comment: Every object property should have a valid name and the value. I see your expected result and I see it only has the values separated by a comma. As others have said, what you **thinking** is not an object.

Comment: This is most likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you need an "object" like that?

Comment: @Thinker , you should start to learn syntax of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not one object

```
{
    name: "a",
    items: [{
        name: "b",
        items: [{
            name: "c"
        }]
    }]
}, // this comma shows you that it's can't be one object.
{
    name: "d",
    items: [{
        name: "e",
        items: [{
            name: "f"
        }]
    }]
}
```

You can't have an object with the two different properties of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You want to **reduce** the array into a single object:

```
var output = x.reduce(function(output, arrayItem) {
  var key = arrayItem.name;
  output[key] = arrayItem;
  return output;
}, { });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like this

```
var x = [{
    name: "a",
    items: [{
         name: "b",
         items: [{
              name: "c"
              }]
         }]
    },
    {
    name: "d",
    items: [{
         name: "e",
         items: [{
              name: "f"
         }]
    }]
}];


function toObject(arr) {
      var rv = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
          rv[arr[i].name] = { items: arr[i].items} ;
      return rv;
}

console.log(toObject(x));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jypahwj4/

Answer (score 0):

One problem that your doing to run into is that when creating an object from that array you will have multiple keys with the same name so each `name:` will be overridden by the next one you try and add to the object. In your function because you are doing `rv[i]` and i is a number that is why you are getting the numbers in your newly created object.

A possible solution would be

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
     rv[arr[i].name] = arr[i].items;
  return rv;
}
```

But this would make the key of the outer part of the object be equal to the `name:` of the original array of objects